# C program not running but getting compiled with no errors

Tags: c

this is the program in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <simpio.h>

long main(){
    long cars_t,years;
    cars_t=80000;
    years=0;
    while (cars_t<=160000){
        cars_t=ceil(cars_t*(1+7/100));
        years+=1;
    }
    printf("Xronia:%ld\n",years);
    printf("Arithmos Autokinhton:%ld\n",cars_t);
}
```

Just an extremely simple program with a while function. But for some reason it doesn't give any output at all. What i have noticed however is that, the moment i remove the while function(and the code inside of it) the program runs perfectly fine. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: `cars_t*(1+7/100)` this is a pretty slow rate of growth to start with, but regardless, `7/100` equals `0` due to integer division, `1 + 0` = `1`, and thus you are simply assigning the value of `cars_t` to itself and it likely isn't even increasing. To avoid this, at least do `cars_t=ceil(cars_t*(1+7.0/100))`

Comment: Yup it worked. Thanks. Believe it or not, this is actually a university project, im on my first year of computer science and they are pretty much starting us off with the basics.

Comment: Also, the return type from `main()` should be `int`.

Comment: You should have put an appropriate printf into the loop and you would have found out yourself. BTW a program compile without error or warnings is by no means a guarantee that it runs as expected.

Comment: ^^^^^^ 'first year of computer science and they are pretty much starting us off with the basics' - demand to be taught basic debugging before you write one more line of code.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program computers:)

Comment: oh i know about debugging, its just that its been months since i last programmed so i need some time and a few reminders to get back into the whole programming mood.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have declared `cars_t` as an integer (long) value, and 7/100 which are also also integers and so evaluate to zero. Hence you get stuck in the loop as `cars_t` does not increase.

Instead you want cars to be a floating value and force 7/100 to be evaluated as floating:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

long main(){
    long years;
    double cars_t;
    cars_t=80000;
    years=0;
    while (cars_t<=160000){
        cars_t=ceil(cars_t*(1+7.0/100));
        years+=1;
    }
    printf("Xronia:%ld\n",years);
    printf("Arithmos Autokinhton:%lf\n",cars_t);
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/vNusyZ9xD